# Return a Javascript Promise value AKA Keras.js prediction

Tags: promise, keras

I'm new to Javascript and getting a bit bogged down with Promises in regards to predictions in Keras.JS

Basically i need to get the prediction value out of a promise (Keras Model) so I can pass it to another function. The following code is taken from the Keras.js github.

```
    var predictions = function () {
      model
      .ready()
      .then(() => {
        // input data object keyed by names of the input layers
        // or `input` for Sequential models
        // values are the flattened Float32Array data
        // (input tensor shapes are specified in the model config)

        console.log('Model ready',x_pred )
        var inputData = {
          "input": new Float32Array(x_pred)
        };

        console.log('input data ready')
        // make predictions


        return model.predict(inputData)
      })
      .then(outputData => {
        // outputData is an object keyed by names of the output layers
        // or `output` for Sequential models
        // e.g.,
        // outputData['fc1000']
        //console.log("outputData", outputData)
        const output = new Float32Array(outputData.output)

        console.log( output )
      })
    };
```

Now, the console reads the contents of my prediction - so the model is doing what I want it to do. But I need to take that prediction and pass it to another function. The following just points to my model promise and the output is undefined.

```
    console.log(outpreds, output)
```

I understand that this is how the promise is meant to work but once the promise has been fulfilled I would really like to be able to do further things with output. unfortunately as I am using Electron/NodeJS I can't access async/await

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just call the other function from the place where you currently have the  `console.log`?

Comment: If that's not viable, you will need to `return` the promise from the `predictions` function and have it resolve with the right value (i.e. also `return` the `output` from the `then` callback after logging it), then you can do `predictions().then(otherFunction);`.

Comment: Ultimately doesn't this just move the endpoint further away? Ideally, I want to generate a series of predictions and then work on all the predictions together. Specifically its an LSTM with the prediction generating characters which I want to add to a string.

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` to wait for multiple promises before working o all generated predictions.